# How to simplify complex integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

The integration function is very complicated， as below, where $\theta, k \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ 
     $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{{e}^{-i\,t\,x}\,\left(1- {e}^{200\,i\,t}\right) \,{\left( 1-i\,t\,\theta\right) }^{k}\,\left(1-{e}^{i\,t\,x}\right)}{{t}^{2}}dt$$
     There ara so many multiplier in the integration, and result should be formed as a function to $x$, and $\theta,k$ as it's parameters. I have no idea about that now.

btw, this is not a home work. it is originate from my question about extreme value of my custom distrbution which is a sum of gamma distribution and uniform distribution, described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27618/how-to-calculate-boundary-value-for-random-variable-which-is-sum-of-variable-in#comment51318_27618).

Above integration is from probablity theory.
I multiply characteristic functions of gamma distribution and uniform distribution, and inverse the result function to get distribution function of new distribution. $\theta$ and $k$ have to be estimated from samples.

I checked another inverse method to convert characteristc function to distribution function the integration can also be expressed as below.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \left( \mathrm{cos}\left( 200\,t\right) -1\right) \,\mathrm{sin}\left( k\,\mathrm{atan}\left( t\,\theta\right) \right) -\mathrm{sin}\left( 200\,t\right) \,\mathrm{cos}\left( k\,\mathrm{atan}\left( t\,\theta\right) \right) \right) \,{\left( {t}^{2}\,{\theta}^{2}+1\right) }^{\frac{k}{2}}\,\mathrm{sin}\left( t\,x\right) }{{t}^{2}}dt$$+$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \left( 1-\mathrm{cos}\left( 200\,t\right) \right) \,\mathrm{cos}\left( k\,\mathrm{atan}\left( t\,\theta\right) \right) -\mathrm{sin}\left( 200\,t\right) \,\mathrm{sin}\left( k\,\mathrm{atan}\left( t\,\theta\right) \right) \right) \,{\left( {t}^{2}\,{\theta}^{2}+1\right) }^{\frac{k}{2}}\,\mathrm{cos}\left( t\,x\right) }{{t}^{2}}dt$$

it is a little bit more complex than the one before.

Comment: Can you confirm or deny if that middle term is actually supposed to be $(1-e^{it\theta})^k$? Otherwise for $k$ not even that large the integral will diverge (and have no principal value either).

Comment: sure, i can add derivation as

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer**, but too big for a comment.
Since you hinted at the probabilistic origin of the integral in question, it is likely that $k$ is actually negative, since the characteristic function of the $\Gamma(k,\theta)$ random variable is $\phi_X(t) = \left(1- i t \theta\right)^{-k}$. Then, for $U_1$ and $U_2$ independent uniformly distributed random variables on intervals $(0,d_1)$ and $(0,d_2)$, and both independent on $X$, and for r.v. $Z = X + U_1 + U_2$ we get:
$$
    \phi_Z(t) = \phi_{X}(t) \phi_{U_1}(t) \phi_{U_2}(t) = \exp\left(i \frac{d_1+d_2}{2} t\right) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{ d_1 t}{2} \right) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{ d_2 t}{2} \right) \left(1 - i t \theta\right)^{-k}
$$
Now, you would like to compute the probability density function $f_Z(z)$ by means of the inverse Fourier transform:
$$
   f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-i t z} \phi_Z(t)  \mathrm{d} t
$$
The you seem to be interested in $f_Z(d_2)$. The answer will depend on whether $d_1 < d_2$, or $d_1 > d_2$.